# stuck with streaming file to string

Tags: delphi, pascal, memorystream, freepascal, lazarus

okay, so I (VERY) recently started playing with lazaruz/free pascal, and I'm a little stuck with reading files with TMemoryStream and it's streaming kin.

I'm trying to write a simple base64 encoder, that can encode strings of text, or files (like images and WAVs) to then be used in html and javascript.

The following code compiles great but I get `EReadError Illegal stream image` when trying to load a file. I'll include the working string only procedure for reference:

```
procedure TForm1.TextStringChange(Sender: TObject);
    begin
    Memo1.Lines.Text := EncodeStringBase64(TextString.Text);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Memo1.Lines.Text := '';
   Form1.BorderIcons :=  [biSystemMenu,biMinimize];
end;

procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if OpenDialog1.Execute then
    begin
     filename := OpenDialog1.Filename;
     stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
       try
         StrStream := TStringStream.Create(s);
           try
              stream.LoadFromFile(filename);
              stream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
              ObjectBinaryToText(stream, StrStream);
              StrStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
              Memo1.Lines.Text := EncodeStringBase64(StrStream.DataString);
           finally
              StrStream.Free;
           end;
       finally
           stream.Free;
       end;
    end;
end;
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

You get the "illegal stream image" exception because the file you're loading probably isn't a binary DFM file. That's what `ObjectBinaryToText` is meant to process. It's not for arbitrary data. So get rid of that command.

You can skip the `TMemoryStream`, too. `TStringStream` already has a `LoadFromFile` method, so you can call it directly instead of involving another buffer.

```
StrStream.LoadFromFile(filename);
```

---

But a string isn't really the right data structure to store your file in prior to base64-encoding it. The input to base64 encoding is *binary* data; the *output* is text. Using a text data structure as an intermediate format means you may introduce errors into your data because of difficulties in encoding certain data as valid characters. The right interface for your encoding function is this:

```
function Base64Encode(Data: TStream): string;
```

You don't need to load the entire file into memory prior to encoding it. Just open the file with a `TFileStream` and pass it to your encoding function. Read a few bytes from it at a time with the stream's `Read` method, encode them as base64, and append them to the result string. (If you find that you need them, you can use an intermediate `TStringBuilder` for collecting the result, and you can add different buffering around the file reads. Don't worry about those right away, though; get your program working correctly first.)

Use it something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  filename: string;
  stream: TStream;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then begin
    filename := OpenDialog1.Filename;
    stream := TFileStream.Create(filename, fmOpenRead);
    try
      Memo1.Lines.Text := Base64Encode(stream);
    finally
      stream.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help, I'm afraid to say I've only spent a couple of hours with the language really, so I'm still struggling.
First, I'm not sure if the function you declared solved this, i did't think it looked like it but i tried anyway and failed: I'm not using delphi, I'm using lazarus, so I don't think Base64Encode() exists.
I tried it with EncodeStringBase64() and had various errors thrown at me, mostly it seemed to want the stream passed as an AnsiString rather than a TStream, I wasn't sure how to solve that, anything i tried seemed to get me deeper in the mud.

Comment: Since you said your goal was to write a base64 encoder, I assumed you would be writing the actual encoding function. The `Base64Encode` function I reference is one for you to write. You're welcome to use whatever you want in its place. The function you apparently already have obviously expects to receive a string, and stands aren't strings. I explained why I think you shouldn't use a string, but the top half of my answer explained what to do if you insist.

Answer (score 0):

I never heard before about `ObjectBinaryToText()`, but looks like funky one. Also, what is `EncodeStringBase64()` function?

At first place, you shouldn't convert binary stream to text to encode it, instead you should directly B64 encode binary data. B64 algorithm is intended to work on array of bytes.

Since Delphi 6, there is `EncdDecd.pas` unit, which implements B64 encoding methods. I'm not sure if Lazarus/FPC have this, but if they do, your code to B64 encode file should look like this (add `EncdDecd` to uses list):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  instream : TFileStream;
  outstream: TStringStream;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    instream := TFileStream.Create(OpenDialog1.FileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
    try
      outstream := TStringStream.Create;
      try
        EncodeStream(instream, outstream);
        Memo1.Lines.Text := outstream.DataString;
      finally
        outstream.Free;
      end;
    finally
      instream.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: [ObjectBinaryToText](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Classes.ObjectBinaryToText) is standard functionality in the Delphi Systems unit, used to read dfm resources and convert them to text. It's used heavily in the IDE, for instance. There's also the inverse ObjectTextToBinary, which converts a text object into its' binary version (used when dfm resources are loaded in your app at runtime to create actual forms and controls).

Comment: For Lazarus/fpc unit base64. Contains both streams and helper functions Encode/decidestringbase64()

Comment: I think what marco said, I'm using lazarus which has it's own base64 classes, and it seems a little pickier than it's doppelgangers

Comment: Crusty Smith: I don't understand what you mean there. Your question talks about objectbinarytotext, which is certainly not related to base64 encoding, as others already have pointed out. If you have new insights, please update your question. The FPC base64 routines work fine of course, I wrote them myself ( :-) )